# Django method to change User email not working

Tags: python, django, forms

I am attempting to create a page where a user can see what their current email is and change it if they would like. I am just testing with a very simple form and a very simple HttpResponseRedirect if the form is not valid. However neither my email is changing for the user nor is my failure response if the form is not valid working. I am not sure what is causing this

forms.py:

```
    class ChangeEmail(forms.Form):
        email1 = forms.EmailField(label=u'Type new Email')
        email2 = forms.EmailField(label=u'Type Email again')
```

views.py:

```
def change_email(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user1 = User.objects.get(username=username)
        form1 = ChangeEmail(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            user1.email = form.cleaned_data['email1']
            form1.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/stupid')
    else:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        email = user.email
        form = ChangeEmail()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form,
            'email': email
        })
        return render_to_response('registration/email.html', variables
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

The URL that I have mapped to render the form is `/user/testuser/email`. I am attempting to put in invalid input in to the fields to get an error message but when I push submit it redirects me back to `/user/testuser` page which displays info about the user. My change email template is below:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Change Email{% endblock %}
{% block head %}Change Email{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<p> Current Email: {{ email }} </p>
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Change Email" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ChangeEmail` is a normal form. These don't have `save` methods - only ModelForms do. You're correctly setting the user email from the form's cleaned_data - but you should be saving the `user1` object, not the form.

Also, it's best not to redirect away on validation failure. Leave out that first `else` clause, and move the variables/render_to_response lines back one indentation level, and the form will be redisplayed with any errors.

Comment: I have changed it to `user1.save()` and made the other changes that you reccommended. However when I put in invalid input it just redirects me to the previous webpage I was one with out displaying an error message.

Comment: How are you rendering the form in the template? Are you using `{{ form.as_p }}`, rendering the fields individually with `{{ form.email1 }}`, or what?

Answer (score 2):

views.py:

```
def change_email(request, username):
        # a common django idiom for forms
        form1 = ChangeEmail(request.POST or None)
        user1 = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if form1.is_valid():
            #check that emails are the same
            if form.cleaned_data['email1'] == form.cleaned_data['email2']:
                user1.email = form.cleaned_data['email1']
                #Save the user object here, since we're not dealing with a ModelForm
                user1.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success')
        # We're presenting them with the empty form if something went wrong
        # and redisplaying. The form's field errors should be printed out in
        # the template
        else:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            email = user.email                
            variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form,
            'email': email
        })
        return render_to_response('registration/email.html', variables)
```

Comment: +1. The key thing is to instantiate the form with request.POST, and then use that form instance in the template if the form is not valid. That will show the errors to the user.

Comment: Will this do things like send a verification email to the user, for instance with Django All Auth?